# Missing keys or something?

Tags: server, ssh

Sup lads!

So I have had problems with connect to my sftp server via ssh because of the keys and executed the command `sudo less /var/log/auth.log`and I found these lines: `error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key`and `error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key`.

I'm not really sure what to do to solve this. I checked etc/ssh and the files were not there.

Thanks on beforehand!

Comment: IIRC the host keys should be regenerated by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`

Comment: Ty for the answer, the host keys got regenerated.

Comment: You can gain one's attention by calling him like this: @steeldriver